# Given a set of URL in the format {FIXED PREFIX}/{NUMERIC ID}/..., how to retrieve the URL with the highest {NUMERIC ID}?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, innodb

I want to make a query that contains the Artist Name and the respective cover video, which is the highest ID on the Link Column. In this example, the second row with ..embd/**125**/...
The link format never changes. I am using PHP ,MySQL and innodb engine

I started by doing an INNER JOIN on these two tables:

```
Id | Artist
1    John Doe
2    Jane Doe
```

And this one

```
Id | Id_Artist | Link 
53   1           http://example.com/embd/123/video/...
54   1           http://example.com/embd/125/video/...
55   1           http://example.com/embd/124/video/...   
56   1           http://example.com/embd/122/video/... 
57   2           http://example.com/embd/128/video/...
58   2           http://example.com/embd/129/video/...    
59   2           http://example.com/embd/130/video/...
```

Which outputs the expected result with all the artists and they're videos

```
SELECT fp.id, fp.name, gl.link AS Video
FROM feed_post_artist AS fp
INNER JOIN gallery gl ON gl.id_artist = fp.id

Id | Id_Artist | Link 
 1   John Doe    http://example.com/embd/123/video/...
 1   John Doe    http://example.com/embd/125/video/...
 1   John Doe    http://example.com/embd/124/video/...   
 1   John Doe    http://example.com/embd/122/video/... 
 2   Jane Doe    http://example.com/embd/128/video/...
 2   Jane Doe    http://example.com/embd/129/video/...    
 2   Jane Doe    http://example.com/embd/130/video/...
```

Is it possible to use regex to compare each artist video and return only the highest link id as a result? ( First 4 rows 125 is highest, last 3 rows 130 is the highest ). I have tried using MAX() but it won't work, obviously.

```
Id | Id_Artist | Link 
 1   John Doe    http://example.com/embd/125/video/...
 2   Jane Doe    http://example.com/embd/130/video/...
```

**EDIT :**

As Julian in the comments suggested, MySQL SUBSTR() solves this particular case. However, when the id goes over 999, it will stop working.

```
SELECT fp.id, fp.name, SUBSTR(gl.link,28,5) AS Video
FROM feed_post_artist AS fp
INNER JOIN gallery gl ON gl.id_artist = fp.id
```

The only part missing is grouping the results to return only the MAX()

Comment: I don't think Regexes are available in common SQL syntax flavors, but you might be able to achieve your goal in this very case using the function `SUBSTR`/`SUBSTRING`.

Comment: Are all the links in the same format?  You might find it beneficial to store the link id in a separate column.

Comment: Yes, the links are all in the same format. Unfortunately I was looking to solve this problem without storing the link id in a searate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      a.Id
           ,a.Artist
           ,g.Link

from                    feed_post_artist    as a

            left join  (select      Id_Artist
                                   ,substr(max(concat(lpad(substring_index(substring_index(Link,'/',5),'/',-1),10,'0'),Link)),11)   as Link  

                        from        gallery as g

                        group by    Id_Artist
                        ) g

            on          g.Id_Artist =
                        a.Id

order by    a.Id
```

---

```
+----+----------+---------------------------------------+
| Id | Artist   | Link                                  |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | http://example.com/embd/125/video/... |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------+
| 2  | Jane Doe | http://example.com/embd/130/video/... |
+----+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This solution seems to work. I am although ending up with a lot of NULL rows between results . Any reason why this happens?

Comment: Where do you get NULLs? Artist? Video?

Comment: Every column except Video column. I counted the total artists and the results of the query match, except for the NULL rows which I believe might be the discarded results of the MAX () ( just guessing )

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You can't get more than 1 NULL for Id_Artist

Comment: I stand corrected. Id_Artist is correct and video column shows the videoid but the artist name is NULL . This always returns the correct video ID: SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(gl.link,'/',5),'/',-1) . What I am missing now is a way to group these results and return only the max value along with artist name and some other columns

Comment: This part of the query is quite straight-forward, please check your data. Take an Id_Artist  with a NULL Artist and look for it in feed_post_artist .

Comment: Just a quick note, the second query does not return any NULL values.

Comment: The optional case solved the issue. Although, I had to remove g.Video from the first select as it gives the unknown column error. The second query works and matches the number of artists but I have no Video with the full link on it.

Comment: This is a tested code. I think you dropped the `as Video` alias. Do you want the full link instead of just the video?

Comment: Yeah, the column name is actually 'link' and Video is the alias. The idea is to have The artist name, some other fields and the full link of the video that passed the max condition.

Comment: Just wanted to drop a quick but very big Thank You for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

if the common part is always the same and the length of the number is the same too you could simply get the max  for string group by

```
  SELECT fp.id, fp.name, gl.link AS Video
  FROM feed_post_artist AS fp
  INNER JOIN gallery gl ON gl.id_artist = fp.id
  where ( gl.artist_id,gl.link)  in 
        ( select artist_id,  max(link) ) 
           from feed_post_artist 
           group by artist_id )
```

Otherwise 
you could replace the common part http://example.com/embd/123/video/...  and get the part of string before the next / 
with this you  should get the number you need

```
substr( replace(link, 'http://example.com/embd/' , '' ), 
    locate(replace(link, 'http://example.com/embd/' , '' ), '/', 1))
```

so you could use a tuple that match th max of the number grouped  by artist_id   properly casted as int

```
  SELECT fp.id, fp.name, gl.link AS Video
  FROM feed_post_artist AS fp
  INNER JOIN gallery gl ON gl.id_artist = fp.id
  where ( gl.artist_id, 
      cast(  substr( replace(link, 'http://example.com/embd/' , '' ), 
    locate(replace(link, 'http://example.com/embd/' , '' ), '/', 1)) ) AS UNSIGNED)  in 
        ( select artist_id, 
           max(   CAST(substr( replace(link, 'http://example.com/embd/' , '' ), 
              locate(replace(link, 'http://example.com/embd/' , '' ), '/', 1)) 
          ) AS UNSIGNED)
           from feed_post_artist 
           group by artist_id )
```

Comment: The code you wrote has a typo ( from feed_post_artist not form feed_post_artist :) ) I believe you are mistaking the common part which is http://example.com/embd/ID-HERE/video/... This code returns the exact same listing as the one in the question

Comment: the common part (alias  'http://example.com/embd/ ) is always the same  ?

Comment: Yes, the common part is always the same.

Comment: All the links are the same except for the ID, and a key at the end. Example:
http://example.com/embd/123/video/234fh1jjd123dasf
The ID is the 123, right after emb/ and before /video

Comment: then select the max link group by artist you should obatin the max numbered .. i have already update the answer .. hope is useful

Comment: Except string ordering != integer ordering.